# How can I make a continuous action process smoothly on a device? (GCD)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, grand-central-dispatch

I'm making a third party keyboard for iOS and without autocorrect, everything runs smooth as butter, especially on older devices such as the iPhone 5 and 4s. Unfortunately, as soon as I re-enable autocorrect, the process starts to lag on the aforementioned devices. How can I prevent this?

**How I set up my autocorrect**

Every time the user presses a key, the word being typed is run through a function that a) tries to complete the word b) tries to correct the word. The words completed and stored are stored in an array and the first element of each array is set as the text of the label in the suggestion bar.

The process itself is pretty quick and the results are logged almost instantly, but typing fast is when the trouble starts.

**My Thoughts**

Which GCD method should I use to speed things up? `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE)` and `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY)` seem like good candidates but I've never used GCD and would like others' opinions. Also, is there any other way of speeding up such a process? It doesn't seem like other third party keyboards are having this problem so I'm probably doing something wrong :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. You should not be running the code that you want to make suggestions in the same thread that you have the user interaction as this will clog up the main thread.

So, I would call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE)` to do all of your analyzation. Just remember, when you update the labels on your keyboard you have to go back to the main queue... For example.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
    //do all of your code that you need to get the values for the labels.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
           //update the labels with the value you got.
     })
}
```